# How does scanf(" %[^\n]", str); work in C Programming?

Tags: c, string

I encountered this in a C program:

```
char str[100];
scanf(" %[^\n]", str);
```

Please explain how it works and why?

Comment: this means scan everything till you encounter `Enter` means newline character

Comment: A good source for answers is the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/), which has explanations of the supported format specifiers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format string consists of two parts:

- a space character, which skips space characters (`' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n'`, etcetera) in the input, and
- the `%[^\n]` conversion specification, which matches a string of all characters not equal to the *new line* character (`'\n'`) and stores it (plus a terminating `'\0'` character) in `str`.

Note however that if the input (after the leading spaces, and before the first newline character) is longer than 99 characters, this function exhibits undefined behaviour, because `str` can only hold 100 `char`s including the terminating `'\0'` character. A safer alternative is:

```
scanf(" %99[^\n]", str);
```

Comment: well if the size of stris greater than 100 should it work except 
scanf("%99[^\n]", str);

Comment: It may work, it may not work. Its behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Or, if you're using a modern libc, `char *str=NULL; scanf(" %m[^n]", &str);` then remember to `free(str)` later.

Comment: can't you just do %s?

Answer (score 2):

`[^\n]` searches for line break

hence it will scan for the string until enter is pressed

Comment: Is it okay to say `searches for line break`