# scanf("%*[^\n]"); usage in a c programm?

Tags: c, scanf

I have an assignment where i need to find out what `scanf("%*[^\n]");` does in a c program. I know that `[^\n]` means that the input is read until `\n` and that `%*` puts the input in the buffer and discards it. I don't understand what usage you can get out of it, because in my understanding it just reads the input till `\n` and discards it then.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038538/how-does-scanf-n-str-work-in-c-programming ?

Comment: `"%*[^\n]"` can be used to clear the input stream until newline. Where `%*` is to ignore whatever read.

Comment: "in my understanding it just reads the input till \n and discards it then." And why couldn't that be a useful thing to do ?

Comment: @JL2210 it's not the same question. There is a * here, not in the question you referenced.

Comment: @chmike It's the same thing, the `*` only discards the input.

Comment: @JL2210 : the question here is not so much *how* it works, but rather *why* you would use it.

Answer (score 1):

> scanf(“%*[^\n]”); usage in a c programm?

It is somewhat common to see yet `fgets()` is a better approach.  Recommend to not use `scanf()` until you know why you should not use it.  Then use it in a limited way.

---

> I don't understand what usage you can get out of it

Example usage: code attempts to read numeric text with `scanf("%d", &x);` but `"abc\n"` is in `stdin` so function returns 0 and data in `stdin` remains.  `scanf("%*[^\n]");` clears out (reads and discards) the `"abc"` in preparation for a new line of input.

```
int x;
int count;
do {
  puts("Enter number");
  count = scanf("%d", &x);  // count is 0, 1 or EOF
  if (count == 0) {
    scanf("%*[^\n]");   // Read and discard input up, but not including, a \n
    scanf("%*1[\n]");   // Read and discard one \n
  }
} while (count == 0);

if (count == EOF) puts("No more input");
else puts("Success");
```

---

Variations like `scanf(" %*[^\n]");` and `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");` have their own corner problems (1st consume all leading white-space, even multiple lines, 2nd fails to read anything if the next character is `'\n'`).