# What is the purpose of this cmp after scanf() in x86 assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly

Doing some basic reverse engineering of x86 assembly code into C, but I am struggling to understand what this particular function, named phase2, is doing at the start.

[Click here to see the assembly code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul8q8.png) (sorry cant post images yet)

Specifically this part right here:

```
call   0x5555555550b0 <<__isoc99_sscanf@plt>>                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
cmp    $0x2,%eax  
jne    0x555555555761 <phase2+86>
```

my best guess is that this translates to

```
if (scanf() == 2) {
```

At first I thought that maybe this was checking if the return value of scanf() == 2 but that doesn't really make sense in this context since the result never seems to be 2.

Comment: Yes, it's checking the number of successful conversions.  If it's not returning `2`, then enter text for that phase of the bomb that matches the format string, e.g. two numbers if it's `"%d%d"` or something.  It's always a good idea to check the return value of `scanf` / `sscanf` before using the results, otherwise it might not have written all the variables.

Comment: You should be able to answer that using a reference to standard library function `scanf`.

Comment: Isn't that `sscanf`, not `scanf`? It's parsing from a string, not from `stdin` (though I suppose `scanf` could conceivably be implemented as `sscanf` against the internal buffer for `stdin`...).

Comment: @PeterCordes Could u elaborate on what u mean by successfull conversions? After printing out %rsi I found `%d %[^\n]` which looks like the format string. Would this mean I am to pass just 1 number?

Comment: @ShadowRanger oh ur right, i didnt know sscanf was a real thing. But what string is it parsing and how would I know? I have printed out all the registers before but all I have found was `%d %[^\n]` from %rsi

Comment: [How do we test the return values from the scanf() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10084224) is another duplicate that explains in general.  `%[` is another conversion, for a string matching a character-set.  In this case, negated, so matching a string of non-newline characters, separated from the number by whitespace.  Found another duplicate for [How does scanf(" %\[^\n\]", str); work in C Programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40038538) if looking up `%[` in the scanf documentation didn't help.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank u, with ur advice I solved the puzzle!